# how to avoid runtime error when calling an operator from a handler or another operator if the called operator has self.report({'ERROR'})

Tags: python, scripting, error, operator

I'm trying to call an operator that has a `self.report()` from both a handler and another operator. It all runs smoothly until it returns to the calling code, at which point it triggers a runtime error and the message is not displayed to the user.  removing the self.report works, but then I have no way of informing the user of problems they need to manually resolve.

Is there a way to call an operator which uses `self.report`, from either a `handler` or another `operator` without getting the runtime error?

Here’s a small example code: open a blend file and change frame to test the handler, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> will let you run it from a popup menu.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2tef36289mftsk/helpme.rar?dl=0